# Ubuntu Software (gnome-software) opens and closes right away

Tags: software-center, gnome-software

I just did a clean install of 16.04 and I'm having an issue with the software center.  The funny thing is I installed Ubuntu a few weeks ago on this same machine and didn't have the issue but I had to wipe it out and reinstall and I'm having issues now.  When I open up the software center, it will stay open for a few seconds and just close, no crash dialog or anything.  When I run gnome-software from terminal I get the message "Segmentation fault" when it shuts down and that's it. No other information

Comment: For some reason, Ubuntu is crashing Ubuntu software because it (Ubuntu Software)  is accessing memory that it is not allowed to access it, more information here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200526/what-is-a-segmentation-fault-on-linux

Comment: I see. Is there a way to fix it?  Or is it a bug with the gnome-software?

Comment: A segmentation fault is almost always due to a bug in the program where it occurs.  
Just to make sure, run it from the terminal as root, if the problem remains, then it is mostly a bug.

Comment: Thanks, When I run it as root, it stays open, however it doesn't fully load  (https://imgur.com/a/zWjI2UF) and I get this message in the terminal (gnome-software:4871): GsPlugin-WARNING **: could not lookup cached macaroon: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets: Timeout was reached

Comment: Try reinstalling the software center with `sudo apt install gnome-software --reinstall`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug ([more information](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1646419)).
The proposed solutions :

- **Solution 1**:

> sudo killall gnome-software
>   sudo rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software

This will first, end (kill) the process of gnome-software if it is running, then remove gnome-software from the `~/.local/share` folder, then it will be recreated automatically when you launch it (gnome-software or ubuntu-software) again.
Now launch `ubuntu-software` or `gnome-software` from the **Unity Launch Button**.

- **Solution 2**:

> sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-software
>   sudo apt-get install gnome-software -f